# How to echo the selected value from an array fetched from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo the selected value from the database to update it then store it

for example I have an asset with category `printers` from table `category` which contains other categories and when I want to edit this asset on the `edit` page I should get a dropdown list contains all the categories and selected on `printers` then if I want to change it I will if not leave unchanged

The array is drop-down from table `category` inner joined with `user_asset` table in the database by `asset_category` as a *foreign key*

this is what I have done so far

```
<label for="basicinput">الصنف : </label>
<?php 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM category");
?>
<select name="asset_category" class="form-control" required>
    <?php while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>">
        <?php echo $row['cate_name'];?>
    </option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give an example ? I'm lost with what you want to do

Comment: Are you talking about adding a filter to your application or what ? I'm quite lost here

Comment: @executable for example I have an asset with category `printers` from table `category` which contains other categories and when I want to edit this asset on the `edit` page I should get a dropdown list contains all the categories and selected on `printers` then if I want to change it I will if not leave unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You can add if check `if ($row['cate_name'] == 'computer') { ?>` and then add `selected` to this option:

```
<label  for="basicinput">الصنف : </label>
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM category");
?>
<select name="asset_category" class="form-control"  required >
<?php while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['cate_name'] == 'computer') { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>" selected><?php echo $row['cate_name'];?></option>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['cate_name'];?></option>
    <?php }
}?>
</select>
```

**Notice:** If you have multiple elements with that category it will select the last one.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is very simple.. let's put this code

```
<label for="basicinput">الصنف : </label>

<?php 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM category");
?>

<select name="asset_category" class="form-control" required>
    <?php while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  if($row['cate_name']== printers)  { ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>" selected="selected">
        <?php echo $row['cate_name'];?>  </option>

 <?php } else { ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>">
        <?php echo $row['cate_name'];?> </option>
    <?php }?>

</select>
</div>
```

The logic is that using `while` loop, checking the condition using `if` class, and when it satisfies make it as selected. Then it will be echo as selected Value.